# How does ConcurrentSkipListSet has Iterators that are weakly consistent? Understanding meaning of 'weakly consistent'

Tags: java, concurrency, iterator, concurrentskiplistmap, java-failsafe

Fail-fast iterator iterates over collection. If collection gets modified while iterating, we get exception. Opposite applies for fail-safe, where iteration is happening on one collection, while write operation happen on copy of it, thus it is how fail-safe works (f.e. CopyOnWriteArrayList).

Can someone explain me how does ConcurrentSkipListSet has fail-safe? There are no copies when modifying collection (like CopyOnWrite classes do), so how does it happen? I read because its Iterator is weakly consistent. I read docs, I still don't understand. (but I do know what code visibility or happens-before relation in concurrency is).

Does anyone have logic and easy to remember explanation, as I am a beginner?

//Example:

```
 ConcurrentSkipListSet<Integer> set = new ConcurrentSkipListSet<>();
      set.add(1);
      set.add(2);
      set.add(3);
      set.add(4);

      Iterator<Integer> iterator = set.iterator();
      while (iterator.hasNext()){
          System.out.println(iterator.next());
          set.remove(4);
      }

OUTPUT:
1
2
3
```

I was expecting ConcurrentException to be thrown here.. Please help :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "weakly consistent" term is defined in the [java.util.concurrent package description](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html):

> Most concurrent Collection implementations (including most Queues)
> also differ from the usual java.util conventions in that their
> Iterators and Spliterators provide *weakly consistent* rather than
> fast-fail traversal:
>
> - they may proceed concurrently with other operations
> - they will never throw `ConcurrentModificationException`
> - they are guaranteed to traverse elements as they existed upon construction exactly once, and may (but are not guaranteed to) reflect
>   any modifications subsequent to construction.

In this case with `ConcurrentSkipListSet`, the iterator does not have a "fast-fail" property, instead it reflects the modification of `4` having been removed from the set.

Internally, `ConcurrentSkipListSet` is implemented with `ConcurrentSkipListMap`, and its iterators are implemented by keeping track of which skip list node should be traversed next. This naturally gives you the "weakly consistent" property: If the next item is deleted, the iterator will still return it. If items beyond the next are deleted, the iterator will reflect those changes.

Comment: Why did they even invent it? Couldn't they fix that problem using snapshot like some classes did? In weakly consistent iterator inserts might not be visible to my iterator, thus be incomplete..

Comment: To get a consistent snapshot of a skiplist you would have to make all write operations wait until the snapshot is complete. ConcurrentSkipListMap was designed to take advantage of a "lock-free" algorithm where no read or write operation has to wait.

Comment: Great! Why don't Stack or Vector use it as well? I noticed they have fail-fast. Was is because they are 'old' and there was no such thing as 'weakly consistent iterator' at a time?

Comment: Yes the reason is historical: "weakly consistent" iterator concept was introduced with the `java.util.concurrent` package in Java 1.5. "Fail fast" iterator concept was introduced with the "java collections framework" in Java 1.2. Vector and Stack are even older than that, and their Java 1.0 methods like `Vector.elements` don't give you any guarantees at all.

Comment: Then why is it called CONCURRENT SkipListMap if there are no locks in the first place? It doesn't fix concurrency issues, so why call it Concurrent? Only thing it fixed is fail-fast iterator, which is now weakly consistent.

Comment: It's called "concurrent" because it gives you the memory consistency guarantees needed for concurrent programming as listed in the [package summary](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html). The implementation happens to give these guarantees without using heavy weight lock mechanisms that force threads to wait.

Comment: 3rd thanks from me! You answered me few times on Stack and every single time your answer helped the most.